# Use Sheet's Array formula to count values in each row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I apply an array formula for:
`=count(D3:AA3)`

It looks like this:
`=ArrayFormula(if(row(A:A)=1,"Count",Count(D1:D:AA1:AA)))`

Too many ":" (colons)?

I could (manually) paste the `=count(D3:AA3)` ...down every row, but I'd like it to be automated.

Comment: Shouldn't `AA` go before `AA1`? Also, you should separate ranges with commas, not `:`

Comment: AA1:AA is the syntax for applying the (array) formula 'down' the column (and telling the function to 'uniquely' calculate a result for each row) ...using a comma "," separates the range from D1 to AA1 ...into "just" calculating what's in column D and column AA (instead of everything between them) - thank you for the comment.

Comment: I think there is no such syntax as `D1:D:AA1:AA` to define a range "from column `D:D` to column `AA:AA`". There is however `D1:AA` (or just `D:AA`) for that, but this won't help as it defines a 2D range but does not make it row-wise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula to count all the number values (`COUNT` does exactly that) row-wise:

```
={
  "Count";
  MMULT(
    ARRAYFORMULA(--(ISNUMBER(F2:O))),
    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:O), 1, 1, 0)
  )
}
```

You can replace `F2:O` with the range you have the data in.

[image]

**Update.**

Count is in column `A:A`, sum - column `B:B`, avg - column `C:C`, avg in a single cell (w/o using count and sum columns) - column `D:D`. `F2:N` cells have random data, some numeric, some text (will be ignored).

Here is a formula for the row wise sum of numeric values:

```
={
  "Sum";
  MMULT(
    ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(F2:O), F2:O, 0)),
    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:O), 1, 1, 0)
  )
}
```

Here is the formula for the row wise average if you have count and sum columns:

```
={
  "AVG";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A = 0, 0, B2:B / A2:A))
}
```

And the row wise average in a single cell w/o using count and sum columns:

```
={
  "AVG one single formula";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      MMULT(
        --(ISNUMBER(F2:O)),
        SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:O), 1, 1, 0)
    ) = 0,
      0,
    MMULT(
      IF(ISNUMBER(F2:O), F2:O, 0),
      SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:O), 1, 1, 0)
    ) / MMULT(
          --(ISNUMBER(F2:O)),
          SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F2:O), 1, 1, 0)
        )
    )
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried adding a picture to explain/show the "Count" formula working (thank you) ...however, I just need to move the "Count" heading title down to row #3 (Column AD).

Comment: @JaysonChabot just place it at the 3rd row. And remove the blank line (the `"";`) to get the values immediately under the Count.

Comment: Confirmed, ...had to change the "2" to a "3" (as well as removing (the ""; ) line

Works like a charm - wow :)
...now, I just need to understand how? - first time I've seen the MMULT 'function' 

Thank you (as well) for making my first 'plunge' into "stackoverflow" worth-while.

={
  "Count";
  MMULT(
    ARRAYFORMULA(--(ISNUMBER(OFFSET(E3:AA3, 0, 0, ROWS(D:D) - 3)))),
    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(E3:AA3), 1, 1, 0)
  )
}

Comment: @JaysonChabot You are welcome! About `MMULT`. It is a function for matrix (a 2D range here) multiplication, a quite basic part of linear algebra, more on this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) and further by the links. In this case just a simple rule should be understood: if you multiply a matrix by a suitable column of only 1s (the `SEQUENCE(...)`) you'll get a column of row wise sums of matrix elements. Also if you multiply a row of 1s by a matrix you'll get a row of column wise sums of the matrix elements. Cont.

Comment: @JaysonChabot The matrix here is `MMULT`'s 1st parameter (`ARRAYFORMULA(...)`) which is a range of 0s and 1s: 0 if the cell is not a number and 1 otherwise. So the row wise sum of this matrix gives a number of numbers in every its row. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess that explains why I got a "#VALUE" when I replaced the "ISNUMBER" ...with the SUM (function)

With the ability to 'count' the number of cells (for a given row) that has a value, I need to divide that row's "SUM" by the COUNT ...to give me an average (for each row)

How to I adjust the (array) formula to SUM the rows?

={
  "SUM";
  MMULT(
    ARRAYFORMULA(--(SUM(OFFSET(E4:AA4, 0, 0, ROWS(D:D) - 3)))),
    SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(E4:AA4), 1, 1, 0)
  )
}

Comment: Wow, I'm still blown away how this MMULT 'function' works ...didn't pay enough attention during linear algebra - I guess :) ...I keep looking for the word "SUM" somewhere(?) and the only difference I see in the denominator portion are these hyphen " - " characters after the MMULT function ...throwing me off, but - hey, it works :)

Comment: @JaysonChabot `MMULT` here gives you the sum. `--(...)` is a useful construction to convert boolean values to numbers (0s and 1s): [description for Excel](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary) (couldn't find for Google Sheets, this stuff is the same).